# How to echo php array in javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms

I have an php array that is generated by server-side code. I want to show the array value in my input field after user pick an option from my dropdown menu. Please see my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name="job_number"]').change (function () {
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    var test="<?php echo $JNarray['selectedVal'];?>"; //where the problem is
    $('input[name="project"]').val(test);  
//I want show value1 to value 3 in my input field when user picks 
//an option from my dropdown menu. 

});

<?php 
   $JNarray['job1']=value1;
   $JNarray['job2']=value2;
   $JNarray['job3']=value3;
?>

<form action='project_manager' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='project' value='show value1 to value3 when user picks an option' />
<select name='job_number'>
<option value='job1'>job1</option>
<option value='job2'>job2</option>
<option value='job3'>job3</option>
</select>

</form>
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for the help!

Comment: what is the actual error / problem? You never mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a cleaner way to do it without having to set the array to a variable. Use a data attribute that jQuery reads with $.data()

HTML:

```
  <option value='job1' data-job-val="<? echo $arrayvalue ?>">job1</option>
```

JS:

```
$('select[name="job_number"]').change (function () {
    var test=$(this).find('option:selected').data('job-val');
    $('input[name="project"]').val(test);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like your answer. Learn something new everyday.

Comment: if you take a look at jQuery mobile...the whole framework is driven by a wide variety of these data attributes for everything from themeing to page delineation

Answer (score 1):

Though, I don't recommened echoing php in js...

```
var test=JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($JNarray['selectedVal']);?>); //where the problem is
```

Comment: I got an error saying undefined variable $JNarry. Is it because javascript attempts to get the array that was created by php before the page was generated? +1 though.

Comment: Javascript should have no knowledge of `$JNarray`

Answer (score 1):

```
<select name='job_number'>
<option value='<?php echo $JNarray['job1'] ?>'>job1</option>
...
...
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('select[name="job_number"]').change (function () {
    $('input[name="project"]').val($(this).val()); 
});
</script>
```

something like that.

Comment: I like your way. Thanks a lot! +1

Answer (score 1):

1. You  have to declare and populate your array before you use it on the jquery code. Move your `<?php ?>` code to the top.
2. Then pass the whole php array to javascript, using JSON as Trevor suggested:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       var options = JSON.parse(<?php echo json_encode($JNarray);?>);
       $('select[name="job_number"]').change (function () {
           var selectedVal = $(this).val();
           var test=options[selectedVal]; //where the problem was
           $('input[name="project"]').val(test);  
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Trevor, however try

```
"<?php echo $JNarray['"+selectedVal+"'];?>"
```

Echoing PHP means your calling your JS from a PHP file, not a good approach dude!, The only thing I would pass is maybe a BASE_URL or FILE_UPLOAD_TYPE/SIZE, even those are ewwwwwwwy